# Can't install setuptools for pypy

Tags: python, pip, pypy, libs

There no file by path to custom distribute pip setup:

```
http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
```

That recommeded for installation.

Setuptools prints the next error on linux debian:

```
$ pypy ez_setup.py
'import site' failed
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openssl_md_meth_names'
$ pypy get-pip.py
'import site' failed
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openssl_md_meth_names'
```

How to handle it?

I want to install the third party python packages for pypy, for example:

```
$ pypy pip install pymorphy2
```

In windows this command works fine:

```
$ pypy ez_setup.py
```

Comment: Where do you see ``http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py``?

Comment: There is no file by path. It is the firs problem. Moreover the setuptools without distribution tool can't be installed with AttributeError

Comment: Every pypy installation tutorial tells about distribute_setup.py and links to this address

Comment: Maybe you should point to a particular tutorial that you're trying to follow.  As asked here, we can't make sense of your problems ("it works for me but I don't know exactly what you did before")